# Authentication through Oauth2

Tags: java, google-analytics

For getting results using Google Analytics, if I access the following URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=gaxxxxx&start-date=2014-07-01&end-date=2014-07-15&metrics=gapageviews&dimensions=gapagePath&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}

I get JSON response if and only if I get an access token using oauth2 playground and navigate to the URL mentioned above, but that access token is only valid for 1 hour, kindly tell how can I automatically authenticate using auth2 so need of access token is not there.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in the shared preferences in Android (or in persistent storage, in case of C#).

If you get authenticated using that token, it's fine; otherwise, request again and save the token again.

Comment: Sorry i dont think u got my questio , while doing in java code i take url variable as string and hit it i get json response if and only if i pass access token which is valid for a hour , but since user cnt keep on changing it ..kindly tell whether there is an way to get response without passing aceess token using auth2